# ROW_NUMBER() as a CASE input

Tags: sql, netsuite, suiteql

CASE is wonky when wrapping around a nested select statement using ROW_NUM() as the comparable.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN rownum = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS col3
FROM
    (SELECT
         col1, col2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col1) AS rownum
     FROM
         table
    )
```

I expected that the first row within the partition is 1, and every other row is 0. But when i tried did, there is only ONE row that's 1, and everything else is 0. however, the rownum still returns correctly.

But my query results looks like this

| col1 | col2 | ronum | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | a | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | a | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | b | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | c | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | d | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | e | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you name your column something else and use that? It seems likely the outer query is treating `rownum` as the pseudocolumn keyword, not as a reference to your inner query's column of that name.

Comment: Works as expected on SQL Server. https://dbfiddle.uk/Dt4uxKPB Maybe a suiteql bug.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you skip the subquery and instead put `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION` etc in the `CASE`?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, [rownum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm) is a special column (pseudocolumn) that returns its own row number which is throw off the case statement.

Rename `rownum` to any other name, ie `row_num`.

```sql
SELECT 
  t.*,
  CASE WHEN t.row_num = 1
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END AS col3

FROM (
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col1) as row_num
  FROM test
) t;
```